# GitHub Fetch polyfill does not summit form body with React form componet

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using the [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) api polyfill by GitHub with React. The example for submitting  a form is as follows:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')

fetch('/users', {
    method: 'post',
    body: new FormData(form)
})
```

My code currently looks something like this inside the component

```
handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('/api/user/', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
},
```

In the app state I am holding the data being sent. It's a simple object.

```
{
    email: 'someemail@email.com',
    password: 'password',
    name: 'Some Name'
}
```

I have tried passing the form itself from the event `event.target` as well as getting the form through an the ID attribute and passing it to the body.

On the server I am using NodeJs to catch the form body in the request. But the request is empty if I don't pass the header `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`. But when I do pass it the entire body is the value with an empty key, but only when I use `JSON.stringify(this.state)`. As follows:

`'{email: 'someemail@email.com',password: 'password',name: 'Some Name'}': ''`

I have also tried passing no headers, and the following header.

```
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
```

I am adding the `fetch` module through `webpack` as a plugin.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    'Promise': 'exports?global.Promise!es6-promise',
    'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
})
```

I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

Currently I have a really ugly hack on the server to convert the `key=>value` pair into an object again, but It's shameful event to share it.

```
var userInfo = req.body;
var tempVals;
//hack to fixed fetch
if(!userInfo.email) {
    for(values in req.body) {
        tempVals = JSON.parse(values);

        if(tempVals.email) {
            userInfo = tempVals;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

...I said it was ugly.

*UPDATE*

Thanks to Michelle, I was able to figure figure out that it was something to do with parsing the form data. I used the `body-parser` module. I could not get the data to be read with my current set up. I had to change my code on the client side to as follows:

```
handleSubmit (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    fetch('/api/user/', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body:  JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
}
```

and in the backend I had to add the JSON body parser to my route  as follows

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.post('/user', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
    //do something with the data
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you posted:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form')

fetch('/users', {
    method: 'post',
    body: new FormData(form)
})
```

is the example for posting form data (see [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152367/62082) for more information). You're trying to submit JSON data, and the very next example in the README is the method you should use:

```
fetch('/users', {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    name: 'Hubot',
    login: 'hubot',
  })
})
```

so your code would look like

```
handleSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    fetch('/api/user/', {
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    }).then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
},
```

You will also need to have appropriate middleware installed in your Express app to parse JSON bodies (for example, [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// ...

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/user', function(req, res) {
    //do something with the data
});
```

Comment: Hi Michelle, Thanks for answer. I have actually tried, both. I tried submitting the form from `event.target`, but the backend gets an empty object as `{}`. I tried doing it as the example as well. In a desperate move I tried all of them from the documentation including sending the data as JSON

Comment: @JoseCarrillo Do you have a body parsing module installed in your Express middleware? You will still need it even to parse form encoded bodies.

Comment: Hi Michelle, yes I am using the  `body-parser` module. `var bodyParser = require('body-parser')`.  This is the setup in my Node app `var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })`

Comment: @JoseCarrillo In that case, I'd expect using `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` and `body: new FormData(evt.target)` (assuming `evt.target` is the form) to work. =\

Comment: Thanks for the help, It does have something to do with a body parser middle ware. I am not sure why. I included the `body-parse`'s json parser and sent the data as JSON with the `application/json` headers that did the job. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I updated my code. If you want to update your answer I can mark it as the answer.