# How upload images on php with method post?

Tags: php, image, upload

I want to upload images with methos post, I've seen tutorials but I haven't seen tutorials that speak about method post.
I'm doing a page and I require use this method.

Answer (score 0):

A post request will have [The Request Payload](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152367/6638533), you can put your image there.

To get the request payload in php, you can use [$_POST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).