# How should I continue a Python Social Auth Partial Pipeline

Tags: python, python-social-auth

The application I am working has an overwritten endpoint for the Python Social Auth `/complete/<backend>/` endpoint.

within our `urls.py`:

```
urlspatterns = [
    ...
    # Override of social_auth
    url(r'^api/v1/auth/oauth/complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$', 
        social_auth_complete,
        name='social_complete'),
    ...
]
```

within `views.py`:

```
from social_django.views import complete


def social_auth_complete(request, backend, *args, **kwargs):
    """Overwritten social_auth_complete."""
    # some custom logic getting variables from session (Unrelated).

    response = complete(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)

    # Some custom logic adding args to the redirect (Unrelated).
```

We are attempting to implement a [partial pipeline method](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pipeline.html#partial-pipeline). The first time the endpoint is called everything works as expected.

```
@partial
def required_info(strategy, details, user=None, is_new=False, *args, **kwargs):
    """Verify the user has all the required information before proceeding."""
    if not is_new:
        return

   for field in settings.SOCIAL_USER_REQUIRED_DATA:
        if not details.get(field):
            data = strategy.request_data().get(field)
            if not data:
                current_partial = kwargs.get('current_partial')
                social_provider = kwargs.get('backend')
                return strategy.redirect(f'.../?partial_token={partial_token}&provider={social_provider}'
            else:
                details[field] = data
```

This redirects the user to the front end in which they fill out a form which calls a *POST* request to orginal API `api/v1/auth/oauth/complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/` with the following in the data:
    {
        'required_fieldX': 'data',
        ...
        'partial_token': '',
    }

### Key Issues

Two things go wrong; When I pdb into `required_info` there is never any data within `strategy.request_data()`. There is still data within the `kwargs['request'].body` and I can take the data out there.

### However

But I am afraid that the second time around we never get into this [block of code](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/def3aa8bb3b048017069b9c7df6a07d8c78df7f4/social_core/actions.py#L38) from *social-core*:

```
partial = partial_pipeline_data(backend, user, *args, **kwargs)
if partial:
    user = backend.continue_pipeline(partial)
    # clean partial data after usage
    backend.strategy.clean_partial_pipeline(partial.token)
else:
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
```

I know this to be true because when I interrogate the database the original *Partial* object still exists as if `backend.strategy.clean_partial_pipeline(partial.token)` was never called.

### Final Questions

Why is the `social_django.views.complete` not processing the *POST* request as expected and as it appears to be in all the example applications. Is there an issue from our overwriting it? Should I just create a separate endpoint to handle the *POST* request and if so how do mimic all that goes on within `@psa` such that I can call `backend.continue_pipeline(partial)`?

Comment: Could [This be the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152367/3791516) All the examples of this working show a form submission, but I am doing `application/json` submission. [This is the key piece of code I need to work](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/def3aa8bb3b048017069b9c7df6a07d8c78df7f4/social_core/utils.py#L175)

Answer (score 1):

I think there's only one issue here, and that's that the Django strategy doesn't look into `request.body` when loading the request data, you can see the method in charge [here](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django/blob/751b5722b14cbaaf1c946bb8d7cfb88942b1614f/social_django/strategy.py#L51-L61). There you can see that it looks for `request.GET` and/or `request.POST`, but not body.

You can easily overcome this by defining your custom strategy that extends from the built-in one, and override the `request_data` method to look for the values in `request.body`. Then define the `SOCIAL_AUTH_STRATEGY` to point to your class.