# Get access without a user using Application Scope - AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using the [MS Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to test an oauth client credential grant flow. I'm following the instructions in the MS Graph documentation [Get access without a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#4-get-an-access-token)

I am making a POST to

```
https://login.microsoft.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

In the Request Body I have the following JSON.

```
{
    "client_id": "***",
    "scope": "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default",
    "client_secret": "***",
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
}
```

When running this query I get the following response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.
        \r\nTrace ID: **\r\nCorrelation ID: **\r\nTimestamp: 2020-11-23 01:14:49Z",
    "error_codes": [
        900144
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-11-23 01:14:49Z",
    "trace_id": "**",
    "correlation_id": "**",
    "error_uri": "https://login.microsoft.com/error?code=900144"
}
```

I'm stumped. From what I can tell, the request body does contain the parameter: 'grant_type'

Any insight on the matter will be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Very thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the screenshot below. Maybe it will give you some idea.

The difference between them is [payload and form data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118249/whats-the-difference-between-request-payload-vs-form-data-as-seen-in-chrome).
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common error. First of all, you cannot use **MS Graph explorer** to test client credential grant flow. We usually use this tool to call MS Graph api instead of requesting an access token, and MS Graph explorer usually requires users login , when you log in as a user, it will automatically obtain a **user token**, which you can see in **Access token**.

[image]

If you need to use client credential grant flow to obtain an access token, I recommend you to use **postman**. In addition, you must note that the request body is not sent in the form of **JSON**, but in the form of **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**. See: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret).

[image]

Comment: @CuriousChad  Ok, try it!