# Unprocessable entity with fastapi post request?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I'm just having a go at using fastapi for hobbyiest purposes. I am getting the 422 unprocessable entity error with my post request

I've created a pydantic model for my products

```
class post_products(BaseModel):
    id: int
    description: str
    price: int
```

Then have a post endpoint created

```
@app.post('/send/data', status_code=201)
async def process_data(product: post_products):
    products_list.append(product)
    if(product in products_list):
        return True
```

which i believe functions like, it takes in a post_products instance adds it to the products_list and then returns true if the add was successful, I then call this endPoint with

```
product = post_products(id=12,description='hello', price=93) creates and instance of the class
product = product.model_dump() makes this instance into a dictionary

response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/send/data", data= product)
```

Sorry Gordon i've updated it with the result. The product is a dict and its this

```
{'id': 12, 'description': 'hello', 'price': 93}
```

Comment: Show us the output of `print(product)` before you call the endpoint.

Comment: @JohnGordon I have updated the question. I feel like i'm missing something super simple that i just can't point out

Comment: @JohnGordon could the issue be the single quotations instead of double quotes

Comment: @Darman In addition to the link above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) as well

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much. I will have a look at this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending your request using form data, while your post endpoint accepts json. Changing to

```py
response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/send/data", json=product)
```

should do the trick.

Comment: That managed to do the trick, can i just ask where i went wrong like as in how were you able to spot that mistake so easily

Comment: Form data is a format used when submitting HTML `<form>`s (which can also be [used in FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/#__tabbed_2_1)), while in most other cases, APIs will use a JSON format, which is what FastAPI defaults to. Here is [another question comparing the two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118249/whats-the-difference-between-request-payload-vs-form-data-as-seen-in-chrome).

Comment: As for how I could spot it so quickly, I've made the same mistake many times, so that's one of the things I always look for when seeing FastAPI return 422 errors.

Comment: @Darman The body of the 422 error message will also tell you _what_ fields was expected that were missing.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you guys so much, its really an uphill battle with coding. I've had a look at what youo both suggested and now i feel comfortable with this error going forward

Comment: @M.O. Thank you also, it wasn't letting me at two users at the same time