# how to upload file and save data at once in web cor api dotnet 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, next.js, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to upload file and save data at same time in coreweb api using nextjs as frontend and asp dotnet core as backend api, I am not being able to send the data to core web api ? How i supposed to send the object data,  below is the json formate data.

```
{
  "sNo": "string",
  "applicationName": "string",
  "status": "string",
  "applicationDescription": "string",
  "entryBy": "string",
  "entryDate": "string",
  "action": "string",
  "softwareBillingDetails": [
    {
      "sNo": "string",
      "version": "string",
      "certificationNo": "string",
      "frontEnd": "string",
      "backEnd": "string",
      "certificatedDate": "string",
      "action": "string"
    }
  ],
  "softwareBillingDocument": [
    {
      "sNo": "string",
      "documentType": "string",
      "includedYN": "string",
      "action": "string"
    }
  ],
  "softwareVendors": [
    {
      "sNo": "string",
      "pan": "string",
      "vendorName": "string",
      "vendorType": "string",
      "contactNo": "string",
      "developerForDistibuters": "string",
      "developerCountry": "string",
      "action": "string"
    }
  ],
  "softwareBillingEquipmentInfo": [
    {
      "sNo": "string",
      "version": "string",
      "equipSno": "string",
      "equipmentName": "string",
      "brandName": "string",
      "modelNo": "string",
      "countryName": "string",
      "manufacturingDate": "string",
      "builtInSoftware": "string",
      "frontEnd": "string",
      "backEnd": "string"
    }
  ],
  "requestedDate": "string",
  "approvedDate": "string",
  "applicantName": "string",
  "designation": "string",
  "applicantEmail": "string",
  "applicantPhone": "string",
  "applicantMobile": "string",
  "website": "string",
  "remarks": "string",
  "softwareBillingDocumentFile": [
    {
      "submissionNo": "string",
      "seqNo": 0,
      "documentType": "string",
      "fileName": "string",
      "pdfFile": "string"
    }
  ],
  "applicationDisName": "string"
}
```

I want to upload file in `softwareBillingDocumentFile in pdfFile` as  I have model as below for uploading the pdf as below

```
  public class SoftwareBillingDocumentFile
        {
            public string SubmissionNo { get; set; }
            public object Document { get; set; }
            public int SeqNo { get; set; }
            public string DocumentType { get; set; }
            public string FileName { get; set; }
            public IFormFile? PdfFile { get; set; }
        }
```

and i am uploading the data in this manner but i am not being able to upload

```
functionName([FromForm] List<SoftwareBillingDocumentFile> softwareBillingDocumentFile, string SubmissionNo`)
     {
    
                    if (softwareBillingDocumentFile[0].PdfFile != null)
                    {
                        IFormFile formFile = softwareBillingDocumentFile[0].PdfFile;
                        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName);
                        if (extension == ".pdf")
                        {
                            Int64 contentLength = formFile.Length / 1024;
                            if(contentLength > 51200) //allow oly upto 5mb
                            {
                                string errorfile = "file size greater than 5mb is not allowed";
                                returnMessage = ReturnHelper.ReturnMessage("err", (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.SeeOther, data: errorfile);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                string fileName = formFile.FileName.Replace(" ", "");
                                 GuidfileName = this.RandomString(10) + "_" + fileName;
                                string filepath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "fileupload", GuidfileName);
                                using (Stream stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create))
                                {
                                    softwareBillingDocumentFile[0].PdfFile.CopyTo(stream);
                                    
                                }
                            }
    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string errorfile = "file type not supported";
                            returnMessage = ReturnHelper.ReturnMessage("err", (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.SeeOther, data: errorfile);
    
                        }
    
                    }
    }
```

how i suppose to send the data, I have tried by creating the formData object and assign the formData object to the pdfFile but it returns empty object and not able upload the fike

Code for upload:

```
const fileUploadHandler = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    formData.append("document", e.target.files[0].name);
    setUserData((prev) => ({...prev,
        SoftwareBillingDocumentFile: [{
            FileName: file.name,
            PdfFile: formData,
            DocumentType: file.type,
            SubmissionNo: "800030444804",
            document: "",
            seqNo: 0,
        },],
    }));
};
```

Comment: You'll need to ensure that your <form> element has a "multipart/form-data" and an <input type="file" /> element. Can you reveal the form code that you have already?

Comment: " I am not being able to send the data to core web api " What's 
 your attempts you have tried  using nextjs as frontend   ? What's  the problem/error messages you get from your attempts. Could you share more code so that we can reproduce  the problem?

Comment: @luke  i am using nextjs

Comment: That's not a useful answer. You haven't shown the code to explain how the user selects the file to upload.

Comment: @QingGuo const fileUploadHandler = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
       formData.append("document", e.target.files[0].name);

   

     setUserData((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      SoftwareBillingDocumentFile: [
        {
          FileName: file.name,
          PdfFile: formData,
          DocumentType: file.type,
          SubmissionNo: "800030444804",
          document: "",
          seqNo: 0,
        },
      ],
    }));
  };

Comment: `const fileUploadHandler = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
       formData.append("document", e.target.files[0].name);

   

     setUserData((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      SoftwareBillingDocumentFile: [
        {
          FileName: file.name,
          PdfFile: formData,
          DocumentType: file.type,
          SubmissionNo: "800030444804",
          document: "",
          seqNo: 0,
        },
      ],
    }));
  };`

Comment: @Rajeev please add the details to your question 

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared how you are actually performing your upload. But you need to pass the `FormData` a single `files` object when you call your API and include the correct header in your request.

Here's a simplified version that shows an example of something that should work for a single file:

```
let file = e.target.files[0];

formData.append("PdfFile", file);
formData.append("FileName", file.name);
formData.append("SubmissionNo", "800030444804");
formData.append("document", "");
formData.append("seqNo", 0);

axios.post(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData, {
    headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data.data);
}).error(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Obviously you want multiple files to be uploaded, which is fine, but currently you're not assigning your object with the single file, you're attaching all of the submitted FormData to the property `PdfFile`, which isn't right.

The above takes the value of `e.target.files[0]` (the first file) and posts it under the property `PdfFile` within `FormData` which is correct.

With this in mind, you can alter your existing code to save the `file` FormData object to the object that you will store ready to be processed and sent to your API:

```
const fileUploadHandler = (e) => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    // formData.append("document", e.target.files[0].name); not required
    setUserData((prev) => ({...prev,
        SoftwareBillingDocumentFile: [{
            FileName: file.name,
            PdfFile: file, // Assign the file to the object
            DocumentType: file.type,
            SubmissionNo: "800030444804",
            document: "",
            seqNo: 0,
        },],
    }));
};
```

You cannot mix JSON and `FormData` together in a single request and just send it up to the server, unless you are going to explicitly convert it to `application/mixed` data and format it differently (IE. Not just JSON with FormData included within it).

So to simplify things, just use purely `FormData` and convert your JSON state into data that your controller can understand, like so:

```
// Get the files from the state
let documentFiles = myObject.SoftwareBillingDocumentFile;
let formData = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i< documentFiles.length; i++) {

    let documentFile = documentFiles[i];

    // Build the form data for the submission
    for (var key in documentFile) {
        formData.append(key + '[' + i + ']', documentFile[key]);
    }
}

axios.post(UPLOAD_ENDPOINT, formData, {
    headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    }
}).then(data => {
    console.log(data.data);
}).error(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

This code sends all of the data up as `FormData` which is what your controller expects.

Comment: i think you didn't get my point, i need to send all the object at once ,  as the formdata need to be parsed on jason object..

Comment: That is the problem that you are having. You're trying to send multi part "form data" (a file) WITHIN a JSON object. This isn't a thing, you can't do that. It's one or the other. See this for more details:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23152367/894792

Comment: The code provided does send it all at once, it adds all of the values of your JSON into the form data ready to be sent to the server. You can't add FormData onto a JSON object. You could send the JSON and the file data in the same request but that would require fashioning a [multipart/mixed](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/multipart-requests/) request but why make things hard for yourself?

Comment: Also your controller specifies `FromForm` which means it expects FormData formatted data and not JSON. That's what the FormData object provides.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it more clear