# Cannot save a post to a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, post, controller

I have an Event app, where I am using a calendar. I have created 2 external routes and controller action to `#save` and `#load` data and I have 2 templates for them. One is `save.json.erb` other one is `load.json.erb`. For now, I have hardcoded the load data from `load.json.erb`, looks like;

```
{"2015-05-06": {"available":"1",
                           "bind":0,
                           "info":"",
                           "notes":"",
                           "price":"20",
                           "promo":"",
                           "status":"available"
  },

"2015-05-07": {"available":"1",
                           "bind":0,
                           "info":"",
                           "notes":"",
                           "price":"20",
                           "promo":"",
                           "status":"available"
  }}
```

So, it shows the hardcoded data on the calendar.

My problem is, when I press submit, it does not give an error but it does not save it to database. I could not figure out the strong params either. I am using `permit!` for now to see it saves to database. Maybe my Event Model and its columns are wrong. Because I could not figure it out what it posts (integer, string etc..)

Here is my `events_controller`

```
....
def load

  end

  def save
    #THIS IS WRONG I SHOULD PUT SMTH ELSE
    @event = Event.new
    @event.save

  end

 def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit!
    end
```

when I select data from calendar press submit it sends this;

```
HEADER:
    event_id:0
    event:{"2015-05-06":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"20","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-07":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"20","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-27":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"demo","notes":"demodemodemo","price":"15","promo":"2","status":"available"}}
```

Also from the log; Is this data JSON?, or I have to use `JSON.parse` somewhere?

```
Started POST "/events/save" for ::1 at 2015-05-02 18:39:42 +0300
Processing by EventsController#save as */* #HERE IT SENDS THE PARAMETERS, BUT I COULD NOT GET THEM
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"0", "event"=>"{\"2015-05-06\":{\"available\":\"1\",\"bind\":0,\"info\":\"\",\"notes\":\"\",\"price\":\"20\",\"promo\":\"\",\"status\":\"available\"},\"2015-05-07\":{\"available\":\"1\",\"bind\":0,\"info\":\"\",\"notes\":\"\",\"price\":\"20\",\"promo\":\"\",\"status\":\"available\"},\"2015-05-27\":{\"available\":\"1\",\"bind\":0,\"info\":\"demo\",\"notes\":\"demodemodemo\",\"price\":\"15\",\"promo\":\"2\",\"status\":\"available\"}}"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "events" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2015-05-02 15:39:42.823906"], ["updated_at", "2015-05-02 15:39:42.823906"]]
   (2.4ms)  commit transaction
  Rendered events/save.json.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 12.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

When I try;

```
def save

    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @event.save

  end

def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit!
    end
```

It gives an error of ;

```
NoMethodError in EventsController#save

undefined method `permit!' for #<String:0x007fcbb99d24c0>
```

So I think it is posted as a string instead of a hash.

For me, there is something wrong with the data it sends to database or the database can not configured for these datas. Because of `#save` action has `@events = Event.new` all the time it creates new event in the database and saves it.So I have to get the POSTed data but I could not get those parameters. I think I have to take the POSTed data and with for loops I have to take those data and save it to database. Could not find a way. Hope someone helps

Here is the full HEADER:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Sat, 02 May 2015 18:42:54 GMT
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26)
Set-Cookie:_demo_session=Snh1Nm5CNWJzTHNITXp5SkRDejNmZzRXRkdoVm5SeEkwUW82WmE5QkFndThkeUdyTEdBK2s3ZVR1aEUxQXpGclpqR202WTIzSGkzNWtIQUdWZXFFeUtmSVpBbnZZNmJnN090YUxXS2c5eFFPVzZOaXJjTGJndGRsS0xBcUhaU0VlMFAvRVdtT05RMHpLcUYrSy9wSElnPT0tLUI2SWFiOHZXRlpqMmpteVloV3Zsb2c9PQ%3D%3D--3533fcf1e966b5c1e766dcc099caa6df4b5c284f; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:7863cf16-0162-4760-8719-d155202eca7a
X-Runtime:0.030455
X-Xss-Protection:1; mode=block
Request Headers
view source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:3126
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_Paint_session=NXN5NVUvemhXcHF2UnF1ZlBXTHhtZVVWODlyVWFoL0tEWU9vWCtOYVp6ck9EUVF6OUs0WTJYV21yWW5VeVhqdndST2JUYTdCdnNnamNzZDJjQXFLNE1CYzlQT3dtcVJiRTJLcmlwaXR3aFdKZUZBVXN4VitWamMzaWdZUUtTQU1mcWhIRFg3SnJwQ2FBK1hmclZ3WmtiODRuTUpVRUVLKzYzQTNuUGxCTURYMHhKN3Z6eUZtbURLS2MybVlNejNoTmo5MVZteUQzcG8wTnB6WUFlR2pRK2UwSHFnUTVua0hUM0VzWitLUTdya1BXVVZ1eTVKUmNCR3pQaEh2djlpcFo3dFU1WmhZYlhSWS9wYTBVSHRTYXc9PS0tbDJHT3A3NVJ1Tm5OczVIREM2emNLQT09--f2703914b69129404c69d1d9dbb446fde16c6442; _Resim_session=cXQ5cEE5ZjFPNU1Jby9ZY0lKWis2TVY1NVlaN2dVZGtSaDdzc3B1QU9saS9yNXNUUHE5N2d1Ym1CZjcxYlNNZjAwbnhPNm9oeEN0aUpNUXZYMXM1Q2ZHWHJuZ3lhdjhxRmxteVR3ZXFvNHdxMFJZcXp6NWZMbk1qWVJyZG5GVFdBWVVtRkp5MHZsZWVNTzZ1aGs4ejAxUzFoZWE2VHVlWCtuWFBpclZnQU5GR2dzeUFZZFBWeEZaSCsxWUhHNmRkQVhwYk9uWW5oVjd4VVA5L2xvRzR3amt2RmE4VTdjUzRHRHQvRC80Rys0V0ZWQ2FCTW01cWtNQ2E2SHUwYWFFQ080VVJkUEduUWxpUjNaUkZldWZsOWc9PS0tcnM2M2UyVCttTEJBbW13SVJQN3RNQT09--3233372784be95cd2d6e2630f7e5e22c17eeff17; _Carrierwave_session=cE4vek43aGlxZ3BrSFNXWU1JaDZQekcxdlVVSnRzNFRMbGNXRGxjOGhNZ0hGNHRaSFpzODQ1YU95WXVnb1VKUlM3Y0xBVFBjYW1paG5FSTh5dVVzYm1LWXNHVXd2RGJnNktaZ0YxY1JtM25Rb1hLMkhUWm5XTElZS1JUejAxSmFvcnE3VzVXTVFoYmdPbTczOE02Wjk4N2hsaTJDRFdLY2pRc1NxYVRNVFBHdkFHbmEvb1U4aEN4T2FOVDZWZGlUMnpJMU0yNkdHNW1acVpYN3NzRkxwQkN2TzRzS0ZBNlMwMGtIMGJ5bWN2QVp5Q3cxQUNIVnExajFDSldsZWhJek1zUjJxVzJyRHRsUDBjQnJsdlB1RFE9PS0tSjViSGdocSs5blRLdTNnUk1GWk9qZz09--068ded1e78c2d70739361e662b995b5470a059c4; _raddit_session=Vy9USHZBa1FodGxON1BMOWFZOHBIazk3eWVSOXh0OW9yUjRmSjJ5Tmg1OXpsMnI2Tm5ZTGQwOHdEMVJnUWhFNG5jRVZEcVhLL3ZCSVdsM1g5S2FTMjYvZWo4U1ovT0xNdkZVT2dJS0VWTkRMcXdRQ0lzTlFRWC9EZ1ZxbDRtYmtLQ1dkZzM3THltSEFvdzJTN010MHVnYytJMzE1R2F0cUVkQlh2bERBRUM4c0NVNnFsTFdmbVB1cURJeDVHUkhKOWZUOG5pUlhFZkxOSkJ3c01uU2paTW50WXRrRW8zRmJtTTBrUm5GWlJvbz0tLUh4ckZqdnA3WGQzRjdmNnAzMXdMcmc9PQ%3D%3D--622d3f9adb9afb871e118d0715921aaf986f82d2; _Cal_session=cjRlSlc0Q2FITHJJTmlTbU5TZjk5aFNFaTczTHRQZW9TR0h1MG4xYVovZG9xaUxyNittWENjbXdib3FLc1J6cXh3dHA5YitaVkZYbFVtaFI2bGxUKzJyM1kvRzJlRFV4b0JibzJ1TTdQS0ZkdVE2eVJJSlZQVXY0Q0thS1NBRzhGUzlaQ1ZRaHppYzJES2V2eXRmVWtBPT0tLWEzVWFIcWl0WnJBRVdnanJ0em1Renc9PQ%3D%3D--03a65bd6c5338108d2d3db62295843f8b3e3eaaa; _fullcalendar_and_rails_example_session=M1h0eFJieVY1ek16OWRtR1JRUGc1eCtsdFZnTDdqWkd3NndWQTFuUzFKdHJpOHlRYSsweHZ6UGZubTV1eEdJZm14NVZxbE1IUHZzRG1id2NVeENERzFlaFF3NzFNWHk0RlltbS8yNmc2aEtnYjJDcGZmY3pZWG0vU0RsU29ST005NDVpdVpYSWtNTURkM3M2RmVvZU8vUStwdUxFNk1TaVJTRDY1Z2FKcEd4QkxZMlpGeUlsUGl5UlNCVWhPNk5qR082T25lZlZ4NkIxY012MjRJaVVTKzFqdUZFMUVjc1VxVnA0UXFwSVFEbW1acE9KMWw1N0xzQWJlYUd6R200Q1VCdkJjUWpTbElrbFhlZ2ZBdnY2WnB1NHdHU2tBQTlQandzekR5SmJkbnVhU08vNWpLNjFuY1UyVUxuZWt2ZWotLTY3TU9jZklCcVR6ZXZQRy9UUCtHTmc9PQ%3D%3D--9bcb70f5196a063e7915b11622953f7935d9166c; _takvim_session=WVJmQVpEbEJUOE9KeVdLK3ZyODRpejI0dzA2aWJPd2dqOGRCaysxOU5VT3lhVkNnNzNIZytvYlpqL2FRZGhTWXZFcWxLc3JYVmoyUVRibGFuelpCczl4eFVjaFVLdkZiRURpUC84cysyUldFbC9VT295SURnMkpDQnFtdldLdUhHeDhRL3NGOG90WS9mWUI1WitocndBPT0tLVp6Mk1VS2VaT0hmMGtwcnhNcnpYMkE9PQ%3D%3D--a215e9c8f635c5c638ccdcd55105c3bdc452760e; SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2; request_method=GET; _Last_session=VnErWEFwazE3dWFBdm94WUVhMXdYWFhKVnViUmtQWUFja0xENjNDTmYxWVAxbjVyVDZrK3pxRlVjUnp0MGQ3R240UWZSK2lNcld5bDVKM2ZYb3JwMTJ1QXpPa0p1cFJOYXFXUllIakVrdnBzVHh2V09YQlZGTHNjTWtNLzFDOXNTdUhYZGNXei80enRwclZkdzBCUzZFcUtEQVFqeDFock15anMrVnVIUHRRPS0tci9lSEMvNFBtVWJ5eW1BSTQ0VUpadz09--46ddca06b8e604506dcfff84e7cc8111c7a1b679; _demo_session=TzE2bi93R2E3ZXVNSHdkZ0MvVnRCTm5BeG1VQ0luMVQrWFJ5a1FhbTc4amNCSGFNazJYTVhVYlRxbEhGejlnREowTTJDVFByYkoveHRpeEx6SlZvRnpaQ3R3UEdWaVRlK25UK29SQmx5Nmplbk9Gb1NNZ0pYdm9PQ3FLeTFKZ25CdkF4USt0clpGN1dMUkxrekxTM3lRPT0tLTZoQ1F4UHg3VExsa3JaMWRxQ1IvTFE9PQ%3D%3D--a430ecd15a69103694b06ec430875e21b66f5e62
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/events
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token:GT/gFRykJMorJu4yPLmLwwGz1EZIwlVSp8XWeO1SOvIVYITeJLAPa1YcYkJOswrkXqMUUFb/jk/DP8JtvLhQYQ==
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
event_id:0
event:{"2015-05-06":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"20","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-07":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"20","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-13":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"35","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-14":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"35","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-15":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"35","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-16":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"35","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-17":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"35","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-20":{"available":"","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"booked"},"2015-05-21":{"available":"","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"booked"},"2015-05-22":{"available":"","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"booked"},"2015-05-23":{"available":"","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"booked"},"2015-05-24":{"available":"","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"","promo":"","status":"booked"},"2015-05-28":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"25","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-29":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"25","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-30":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"25","promo":"","status":"available"},"2015-05-31":{"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"25","promo":"","status":"available"}}
```

and Here is my database schema;

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150502145455) do

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
    t.string   "status"
    t.float    "price"
    t.float    "promo"
    t.integer  "available"
    t.text     "info"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.boolean  "bind"
    t.string   "time"
    t.string   "p"
    t.string   "event_id"
  end

end
```

**EDIT 1**:
Here is the Jquery request;

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#backend').DOPBackendBookingCalendarPRO({

        'DataURL': '/events/load', #TO LOAD DATA
        'SaveURL': '/events/save'  #TO SAVE DATA
    });
});
</script>
```

I have shared `load.js.erb` file as it is harcoded right now. But `save.js.erb` file is empty. When I created the url, rails asked me to define template. But `#create` action does not have a template,right?.
This calendar was written for php but I am trying to use it on RoR. The guy who wrote it, I do not know why, they defined 2 post urls one to retrieve data one to send data. Normally, one of them should be get, right?. That is why I created 2 post urls in `routes.rb`.Anyway. If you can help, I can send the calendar project I do not know how, but you see their backend.js file. Maybe I should change something there. Thank you

Here at the top of the backend.js file, I have ;

```
 Schedule = {},
```

And there is this function in backend..js file to load data

```
                 parseCalendarData:function(){
                        $.post(DataURL, {event_id:ID}, function(data){
                            console.log(typeof data); //THIS RETURNS OBJECT
                            if(typeof data === 'object') {
                        Schedule = data; 
                        }
                        else {
                            data = $.trim(data).replace(/\\/gi, '');

                        if (data != ''){
                                Schedule = JSON.parse(data);
                            }
                        }
                            methods.initCalendar();
                        });
                    },
```

Before save data, here is the code to set submitted data, probably the problem is there;

```
setData:function(){// Set submited data.
                        var y, m, d, noDays, key,
                        startDate, sYear, sMonth, sDay,
                        endDate, eYear, eMonth, eDay,
                        fromMonth, toMonth, fromDay, toDay,
                        availableValue = $('#DOPBCP_available').val(),
                        bindValue = 0,
                        infoValue = $('#DOPBCP_info').val().replace(/\n/gi, '<br />'),
                        notesValue = $('#DOPBCP_notes').val().replace(/\n/gi, '<br />'),
                        priceValue = $('#DOPBCP_price').val() != undefined ? $('#DOPBCP_price').val():'',
                        promoValue = $('#DOPBCP_promo').val() != undefined ? $('#DOPBCP_promo').val():'',
                        statusValue = $('#DOPBCP_status').val();

                        startDate = dayStartSelection < dayEndSelection ? dayStartSelection.split('_')[1]:dayEndSelection.split('_')[1];
                        endDate = dayStartSelection < dayEndSelection ? dayEndSelection.split('_')[1]:dayStartSelection.split('_')[1];

                        sYear = parseInt(startDate.split('-')[0], 10);
                        sMonth = parseInt(startDate.split('-')[1], 10);
                        sDay = parseInt(startDate.split('-')[2], 10);

                        eYear = parseInt(endDate.split('-')[0], 10);
                        eMonth = parseInt(endDate.split('-')[1], 10);
                        eDay = parseInt(endDate.split('-')[2], 10);

                        if (Schedule[methods.previousDay(startDate)] != undefined){
                            if (Schedule[methods.previousDay(startDate)]['bind'] == 1){
                                Schedule[methods.previousDay(startDate)]['bind'] = 0;
                            }
                            else if (Schedule[methods.previousDay(startDate)]['bind'] == 2){
                                Schedule[methods.previousDay(startDate)]['bind'] = 3;
                            }
                        }

                        if (Schedule[methods.nextDay(endDate)] != undefined){
                            if (Schedule[methods.nextDay(endDate)]['bind'] == 2){
                                Schedule[methods.nextDay(endDate)]['bind'] = 1;
                            }
                            else if (Schedule[methods.nextDay(endDate)]['bind'] == 3){
                                Schedule[methods.nextDay(endDate)]['bind'] = 0;
                            }
                        }

                        for (y=sYear; y<=eYear; y++){
                            fromMonth = 1;

                            if (y == sYear){
                                fromMonth = sMonth;
                            }

                            toMonth = 12;

                            if (y == eYear){
                                toMonth = eMonth;
                            }

                            for (m=fromMonth; m<=toMonth; m++){
                                noDays = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
                                fromDay = 1;

                                if (y == sYear && m == sMonth){
                                    fromDay = sDay;
                                }

                                toDay = noDays;

                                if (y == eYear && m == eMonth){
                                    toDay = eDay;
                                }

                                for (d=fromDay; d<=toDay; d++){
                                    key = y+'-'+prototypes.timeLongItem(m)+'-'+prototypes.timeLongItem(d);

                                    if ($('#DOPBCP_group').is(':checked')){
                                        if (key == startDate){
                                            bindValue = 1;
                                        }
                                        else if (key == endDate){
                                            bindValue = 3;
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            bindValue = 2;
                                        }
                                    }
                                      //HERE IS THE PROBLEM I GUESS
                                    Schedule[key] = {"available": availableValue,
                                                     "bind": bindValue,
                                                     "info": infoValue,
                                                     "notes": notesValue,
                                                     "price": priceValue,
                                                     "promo": promoValue,
                                                     "status": statusValue};
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        methods.saveData();
                    },
```

Lastly the save function in js file;

```
                   saveData:function(){// Save data.
                        var today = new Date(),
                        dd = prototypes.timeLongItem(today.getDate()),
                        mm = prototypes.timeLongItem(today.getMonth()+1),
                        yyyy = today.getFullYear();

                        for (var day in Schedule){
                            if (day < yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd){
                                delete Schedule[day];
                            }
                        }

                        methods.hideForm();
                        methods.generateCalendar(StartYear, dayStartSelectionCurrMonth);

                        $.post(SaveURL, {event_id:ID, event:JSON.stringify(Schedule)}, function(data){});
                    },
```

PS: I have tried this in the events controller;

```
def save
    respond_to do |format|
      @event = Event.new(event_params)
      @event.save

      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @event, :content_type => 'application/json'  }
    end
  end
```

But content type did not change.

**EDIT 2:**

Sorry for giving you so much trouble but I am really trying to learn. I have changed `$.pos`t to `$.ajax`and I changed the controller as you suggested. Now it try to post array and I am planing to iterate over the hash to get datas and save it. As you said I can then loop over `params[:event]` as it contains all the data, right?.Because of the multiple data it gives an nil error, that is why I would like to loop over them(I changed the `#create` as you said);

```
NoMethodError in EventsController#create

undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass
```

I think this is because Schedule; (key is the selected date)

```
Schedule[key]  =    {"date": key,
                     "available": availableValue,
                     "bind": bindValue,
                     "info": infoValue,
                     "notes": notesValue,
                     "price": priceValue,
                     "promo": promoValue,
                     "status": statusValue};
}
```

This is what comes from the Network tab;

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:94953
Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 03 May 2015 15:26:09 GMT
Server:WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.2.1/2015-02-26)
X-Request-Id:1d59e6cd-726f-4eb0-afdf-92205c8a0974
X-Runtime:0.390420
Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:1687
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:_Paint_session=NXN5NVUvemhXcHF2UnF1ZlBXTHhtZVVWODlyVWFoL0tEWU9vWCtOYVp6ck9EUVF6OUs0WTJYV21yWW5VeVhqdndST2JUYTdCdnNnamNzZDJjQXFLNE1CYzlQT3dtcVJiRTJLcmlwaXR3aFdKZUZBVXN4VitWamMzaWdZUUtTQU1mcWhIRFg3SnJwQ2FBK1hmclZ3WmtiODRuTUpVRUVLKzYzQTNuUGxCTURYMHhKN3Z6eUZtbURLS2MybVlNejNoTmo5MVZteUQzcG8wTnB6WUFlR2pRK2UwSHFnUTVua0hUM0VzWitLUTdya1BXVVZ1eTVKUmNCR3pQaEh2djlpcFo3dFU1WmhZYlhSWS9wYTBVSHRTYXc9PS0tbDJHT3A3NVJ1Tm5OczVIREM2emNLQT09--f2703914b69129404c69d1d9dbb446fde16c6442; _Resim_session=cXQ5cEE5ZjFPNU1Jby9ZY0lKWis2TVY1NVlaN2dVZGtSaDdzc3B1QU9saS9yNXNUUHE5N2d1Ym1CZjcxYlNNZjAwbnhPNm9oeEN0aUpNUXZYMXM1Q2ZHWHJuZ3lhdjhxRmxteVR3ZXFvNHdxMFJZcXp6NWZMbk1qWVJyZG5GVFdBWVVtRkp5MHZsZWVNTzZ1aGs4ejAxUzFoZWE2VHVlWCtuWFBpclZnQU5GR2dzeUFZZFBWeEZaSCsxWUhHNmRkQVhwYk9uWW5oVjd4VVA5L2xvRzR3amt2RmE4VTdjUzRHRHQvRC80Rys0V0ZWQ2FCTW01cWtNQ2E2SHUwYWFFQ080VVJkUEduUWxpUjNaUkZldWZsOWc9PS0tcnM2M2UyVCttTEJBbW13SVJQN3RNQT09--3233372784be95cd2d6e2630f7e5e22c17eeff17; _Carrierwave_session=cE4vek43aGlxZ3BrSFNXWU1JaDZQekcxdlVVSnRzNFRMbGNXRGxjOGhNZ0hGNHRaSFpzODQ1YU95WXVnb1VKUlM3Y0xBVFBjYW1paG5FSTh5dVVzYm1LWXNHVXd2RGJnNktaZ0YxY1JtM25Rb1hLMkhUWm5XTElZS1JUejAxSmFvcnE3VzVXTVFoYmdPbTczOE02Wjk4N2hsaTJDRFdLY2pRc1NxYVRNVFBHdkFHbmEvb1U4aEN4T2FOVDZWZGlUMnpJMU0yNkdHNW1acVpYN3NzRkxwQkN2TzRzS0ZBNlMwMGtIMGJ5bWN2QVp5Q3cxQUNIVnExajFDSldsZWhJek1zUjJxVzJyRHRsUDBjQnJsdlB1RFE9PS0tSjViSGdocSs5blRLdTNnUk1GWk9qZz09--068ded1e78c2d70739361e662b995b5470a059c4; _raddit_session=Vy9USHZBa1FodGxON1BMOWFZOHBIazk3eWVSOXh0OW9yUjRmSjJ5Tmg1OXpsMnI2Tm5ZTGQwOHdEMVJnUWhFNG5jRVZEcVhLL3ZCSVdsM1g5S2FTMjYvZWo4U1ovT0xNdkZVT2dJS0VWTkRMcXdRQ0lzTlFRWC9EZ1ZxbDRtYmtLQ1dkZzM3THltSEFvdzJTN010MHVnYytJMzE1R2F0cUVkQlh2bERBRUM4c0NVNnFsTFdmbVB1cURJeDVHUkhKOWZUOG5pUlhFZkxOSkJ3c01uU2paTW50WXRrRW8zRmJtTTBrUm5GWlJvbz0tLUh4ckZqdnA3WGQzRjdmNnAzMXdMcmc9PQ%3D%3D--622d3f9adb9afb871e118d0715921aaf986f82d2; _Cal_session=cjRlSlc0Q2FITHJJTmlTbU5TZjk5aFNFaTczTHRQZW9TR0h1MG4xYVovZG9xaUxyNittWENjbXdib3FLc1J6cXh3dHA5YitaVkZYbFVtaFI2bGxUKzJyM1kvRzJlRFV4b0JibzJ1TTdQS0ZkdVE2eVJJSlZQVXY0Q0thS1NBRzhGUzlaQ1ZRaHppYzJES2V2eXRmVWtBPT0tLWEzVWFIcWl0WnJBRVdnanJ0em1Renc9PQ%3D%3D--03a65bd6c5338108d2d3db62295843f8b3e3eaaa; _fullcalendar_and_rails_example_session=M1h0eFJieVY1ek16OWRtR1JRUGc1eCtsdFZnTDdqWkd3NndWQTFuUzFKdHJpOHlRYSsweHZ6UGZubTV1eEdJZm14NVZxbE1IUHZzRG1id2NVeENERzFlaFF3NzFNWHk0RlltbS8yNmc2aEtnYjJDcGZmY3pZWG0vU0RsU29ST005NDVpdVpYSWtNTURkM3M2RmVvZU8vUStwdUxFNk1TaVJTRDY1Z2FKcEd4QkxZMlpGeUlsUGl5UlNCVWhPNk5qR082T25lZlZ4NkIxY012MjRJaVVTKzFqdUZFMUVjc1VxVnA0UXFwSVFEbW1acE9KMWw1N0xzQWJlYUd6R200Q1VCdkJjUWpTbElrbFhlZ2ZBdnY2WnB1NHdHU2tBQTlQandzekR5SmJkbnVhU08vNWpLNjFuY1UyVUxuZWt2ZWotLTY3TU9jZklCcVR6ZXZQRy9UUCtHTmc9PQ%3D%3D--9bcb70f5196a063e7915b11622953f7935d9166c; _takvim_session=WVJmQVpEbEJUOE9KeVdLK3ZyODRpejI0dzA2aWJPd2dqOGRCaysxOU5VT3lhVkNnNzNIZytvYlpqL2FRZGhTWXZFcWxLc3JYVmoyUVRibGFuelpCczl4eFVjaFVLdkZiRURpUC84cysyUldFbC9VT295SURnMkpDQnFtdldLdUhHeDhRL3NGOG90WS9mWUI1WitocndBPT0tLVp6Mk1VS2VaT0hmMGtwcnhNcnpYMkE9PQ%3D%3D--a215e9c8f635c5c638ccdcd55105c3bdc452760e; SQLiteManager_currentLangue=2; request_method=GET; _Last_session=VnErWEFwazE3dWFBdm94WUVhMXdYWFhKVnViUmtQWUFja0xENjNDTmYxWVAxbjVyVDZrK3pxRlVjUnp0MGQ3R240UWZSK2lNcld5bDVKM2ZYb3JwMTJ1QXpPa0p1cFJOYXFXUllIakVrdnBzVHh2V09YQlZGTHNjTWtNLzFDOXNTdUhYZGNXei80enRwclZkdzBCUzZFcUtEQVFqeDFock15anMrVnVIUHRRPS0tci9lSEMvNFBtVWJ5eW1BSTQ0VUpadz09--46ddca06b8e604506dcfff84e7cc8111c7a1b679; _demo_session=R1dIMnpjMU1BTkszczFzZTR2Zmk3cFMyUVU2Yk12eEwyZ2poR2RWUzhQWEtPbEM5UkMrQXRJb21oc1grWkFNNlpVM2VwMElvMnI1YUN2UlFVeXR2KytqYzJyN3AxeS9lM3gxVlNhLysxQzNLMklQOGszdUZBaEREMGQwZVMzc09BNFVndjRZaGQzY25KZGwrR0wyME5nPT0tLUEreS9acGZTWUhzdXdOc0hrVW5WYVE9PQ%3D%3D--9a636d832705858099e968c44c959b12980b6e99
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/events
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
X-CSRF-Token:BaHKI75O/nhl2kbiQDxSvJeZHiUAlTttTPGd0b/usf4J/q7ohlrV2RjgypIyNtObyIneMx6o4HAoC4nE7gTbbQ==
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Data
view source
view URL encoded
event[2015-05-06][available]:1
event[2015-05-06][bind]:0
event[2015-05-06][info]:
event[2015-05-06][notes]:
event[2015-05-06][price]:20
event[2015-05-06][promo]:
event[2015-05-06][status]:available
event[2015-05-07][available]:1
event[2015-05-07][bind]:0
event[2015-05-07][info]:
event[2015-05-07][notes]:
event[2015-05-07][price]:20
event[2015-05-07][promo]:
event[2015-05-07][status]:available
event[2015-05-20][date]:2015-05-20
event[2015-05-20][available]:1
event[2015-05-20][bind]:0
event[2015-05-20][info]:
event[2015-05-20][notes]:
event[2015-05-20][price]:
event[2015-05-20][promo]:
event[2015-05-20][status]:available
event[2015-05-21][date]:2015-05-21
event[2015-05-21][available]:1
event[2015-05-21][bind]:0
event[2015-05-21][info]:
event[2015-05-21][notes]:
event[2015-05-21][price]:
event[2015-05-21][promo]:
event[2015-05-21][status]:available
event[2015-05-22][date]:2015-05-22
event[2015-05-22][available]:1
event[2015-05-22][bind]:0
event[2015-05-22][info]:
event[2015-05-22][notes]:
event[2015-05-22][price]:
event[2015-05-22][promo]:
event[2015-05-22][status]:available
event[2015-05-23][date]:2015-05-23
event[2015-05-23][available]:1
event[2015-05-23][bind]:0
event[2015-05-23][info]:
event[2015-05-23][notes]:
event[2015-05-23][price]:
event[2015-05-23][promo]:
event[2015-05-23][status]:available
```

**EDIT 3:**

```
h = {"event"=>{"2015-05-06"=>{"available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"20", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}, "2015-05-07"=>{"available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"20", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}, "2015-05-18"=>{"date"=>"2015-05-18", "available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"30", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}, "2015-05-19"=>{"date"=>"2015-05-19", "available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"30", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}, "2015-05-20"=>{"date"=>"2015-05-20", "available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"30", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}, "2015-05-21"=>{"date"=>"2015-05-21", "available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"30", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}, "2015-05-22"=>{"date"=>"2015-05-22", "available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"30", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}, "2015-05-23"=>{"date"=>"2015-05-23", "available"=>"1", "bind"=>"0", "info"=>"", "notes"=>"", "price"=>"30", "promo"=>"", "status"=>"available"}}}


h.each do |key, value|
  puts key
  value.each do |key2, value2|
    puts key2
    value2.each do |k, v|
    puts k
    puts v
    end
  end
end
```

Something like the code works fine to get the key and values, however I do not know if that works if I put it to controller.Then I should save it to database. I surely think there must be a easier way. But I am dependent on the calendar js code that the person wrote. Sorry again asking too much. If you can guide me I appreciate. Thank you again

In my controller #create action I am able to iterate over key and values;
Now I have to figure out how to save them

```
def create
 h = params[:event] 
    h.each do |key, value|
      puts key
      value.each do |key2, value2|
        puts key2
        puts value2
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't detailed how you are actually sending the JSON request but two things are going wrong:

Your save action expects a hash with the key event with:

```
{
  event: {
    title: "foo"
    # more attributes ...
  }
}
```

But you're trying to send the parameters for several dates at the same time.

```
event:{ 
 "2015-05-06": {"available":"1","bind":0,"info":"","notes":"","price":"20","promo":"","status":"available"}
 #... more events
}
```

Also you sending the request with the wrong `Content-Type

Your request is sent with:

```
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Not:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;
```

[differences in application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523/differences-in-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)

### Added in response to edit of the question:

Use `jQuery.ajax` instead of `jQuery.post` and it will stringify the data for you - that way jQuery will take care of browsers which don't have native JSON support.

```
$.ajax(SaveURL, {
  method: 'POST',
  data: { event: Schedule },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Now that you are sending the correct request type jQuery will merge the post data into `params`.

But this still doesn't fix the issue that `Schedule` contains the attributes for multiple Events. I would start by creating a simple route which accepts the parameters for a single event. In Rails conventions we call that action `create` not `save`.

```
   class EventsController
     # ... 

     # POST /events
     def create
        @event.new(params[:event])
        if (@event.save) 
           render json: @event, status: :created
        else
           # ... what do we do if validation fails?
        end
     end

     # ...  

     private 

     def create_params
        params.permit(:event).allow(:available, :bind, :info, :notes, :price, :promo, :status)
     end  
   end
```

You can generate a full set of restful routes for events by adding this to your `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :events
```

which generates the following routes:

```
    Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                Controller#Action
    events GET    /events(.:format)          events#index
           POST   /events(.:format)          events#create
 new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)      events#new
edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format) events#edit
     event GET    /events/:id(.:format)      events#show
           PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           PUT    /events/:id(.:format)      events#update
           DELETE /events/:id(.:format)      events#destroy
```

At your skill level I would not bother trying to create a controller action which creates several Events at once, and I'm not going to instruct how to do it here since it would be really lengthy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 2 things, 1. what do you mean by; You haven't detailed how you are actually sending the JSON request and how can change this several dates into hash. 2. How can I use `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8;`. I mean where, sorry but I am new to RoR. Thank you

Comment: I also do not know how I can change those dates to key values. Maybe I should change js file, or find a way to loop through all data and save them to database

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, I wonder which variable contains the data comes from post request. As far as know it is params. So in params I should see the hash, right?

Comment: You must have sent an AJAX request with something like jQuery but you're doing it wrong. Show the code. Rails merges post variables into `params` http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters

Comment: I have answered some of the issues, but your whole architecture is just weird and plain wrong. I have no idea what you're trying to achieve and why you are doing it in such a convoluted way. If you have data in a file - why open it in a browser to send the the server to start with? Are you trying to edit existing resources or create new ones? I would start with https://www.railstutorial.org/ and learn how rails applications are built.

Comment: Thank you for your instructions. I have allready followed railstutorials i am just lack of jquery knowledge. The calendar is weird in general. The guy who wrote it, asks for 2 post urls, not 1 get and 1 post. I know i can use create action, however I wanted to use 2 custom actions. I am trying save selected data to database. Because user can select date range that is why it sends multiple dates with their attributes. I will try what you have suggested but I think I can make params array by manuplating the code to set data in js file which i posted. Because it defines the Schedule

Comment: My problem is that, Schedule has to contain multiple events because user can select date range