# Yelp Fusion: Cannot get Tokens

Tags: node.js, http-post, yelp

I'm trying to access the Yelp fusion API. I am following the [documentation](https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/authentication) and came to this code:

```
const request = require('request');

// As you can see the common error of there being a whitespace
// in one of these is not the case here
const clientId = 'O<removed>w';
const clientSecret = 'm<removed>r';

const options = {
    url: 'https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    json: {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': clientId,
        'client_secret': clientSecret
    }
};

request(options, (err, res, body) => {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(body);
});
```

Using APIGee I am getting a correct response with this exact same call, however on my OVH VPS I am getting this error: (Note that this is from the body variable)

```
{ error:
    { code: 'VALIDATION_ERROR',
      description: 'client_id or client_secret parameters not found. Make sure to provide client_id and client_secret in the body with the application/x-www-form-urlencoded content-type' } }
```

I believe I am setting up the call correctly. Can anyone point me in the right direction please? Thank you!

Comment: Look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523/differences-in-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: Can you check with `content-type` with lower case?

Comment: @abdulbarik Didn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the options to submit the data correctly. Data goes into `body` field and if it's a JSON object instead a string you need to set `json:true`

```
const options = {
    url: 'https://api.yelp.com/oauth2/token',
    method: 'POST', 
    body: {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': clientId,
        'client_secret': clientSecret
    },
    json: true
};
```

Also, I don't think headers is required.

Check Request [options documentation](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback)

Comment: I now have [this code](https://hastebin.com/hokexidixa.scala)

and I'm getting [this error](https://hastebin.com/konifaxana.vbs)

It seems to be an error in the request library. Note that without the header section it just gives me the error I mentioned in my original post. Any ideas? Thank you