# empty POST request with react/axios

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I'm new to node.js and react. I've built a back end api to expose **CRUD endpoints** for a `Products` model with three fields: `Title`, `Description` and `Price`. I've used **node/express** for the server with an **SQLite** db file.

I've tested the endpoints using postman and can successfully access all the products, retrieve a single product, add a new product (but only with the header set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`), and delete a product.

I'm loosely following a tutorial building the front end with **react** and using **axios** to make http requests. I can read without issue so get all and get one by ID is working.

However, I've hit a wall with my post request. If I send a post request I get this error backend in the api server console -

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: notNull Violation: product
```

And on the front end after about a couple of minutes from sending the request I get:

```
XHR failed loading: POST "http://localhost:3000/api/products/new".
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:178
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:59
Promise resolved (async)
request @ Axios.js:51
Axios.(anonymous function) @ Axios.js:71
wrap @ bind.js:9
NewProduct._this.createHandler @ ProductNew.js:25
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:452
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:836
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:858
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:956
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:967
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:935
processEventQueue @ react-dom.development.js:1112
runEventQueueInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3607
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3616
handleTopLevelImpl @ react-dom.development.js:3347
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11082
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2330
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:3421
09:59:59.293 ProductNew.js:30 

Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:16)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

If I remove the validation a new product is successfully added to the database, but all the values are *null*.

This is my ProductNew.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from'axios';
import ButtonAdd from '../components/Buttons/ButtonAdd';

class NewProduct extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    price: ''
  }
  createHandler = () => {
    const data = {
      Title: this.state.title,
      Description: this.state.description,
      Price: this.state.price
    };
    console.log('Raw data is: ' + Object.entries(data));
    // => Raw data is: Title,burger,Description,bun,Price,5

    const header = {
      ContentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      Accept: 'application/json'
    };
    const querystring = require('querystring');
    console.log(querystring.stringify(data));
    // => Title=burger&Description=bun&Price=5

    console.log('Data is:' + JSON.stringify(data));
    // => Data is:{"Title":"burger","Description":"bun","Price":"5"}

    axios.post('/api/products/new', querystring.stringify(data), header)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='NewPost'>
        <h1>Add a Product</h1>
        <label>Title</label>
        <textarea rows='4' value={this.state.title} onChange={(event) => this.setState({title: event.target.value})} />
        <label>Description</label>
        <textarea rows='6' value={this.state.description} onChange={(event) => this.setState({description: event.target.value})} />
        <label>Price</label>
        <input type='number' value={this.state.price} onChange={(event) => this.setState({price: event.target.value})} />
        // ButtonAdd.js onClick={props.create} added to <Button> tag
        <ButtonAdd create={this.createHandler}>Add New Product</ButtonAdd>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default NewProduct;
```

I found this [issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/751) on github which I hoped would have solved my problem. I've added various console.log to follow what is happening with the state data through the script but I can't see why my POST request is empty. I'd appreciate any pointers as to what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help you somehow. I think you have a problem with your axios request structure.

Docs say: `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`

Instead of putting headers directly, as the last parameter:

`axios.post('/api/products/new', querystring.stringify(data), header)`

you should have a config object that **contains** headers and then pass it as the last parameter:

```
const config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  }
};

axios.post('/api/products/new', querystring.stringify(data), config)
```

Comment: Also, make sure you are using correct content type in your headers, as @aslantorret mentioned

Comment: what if there is no data to post ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you may be using an incorrect Content type. The proper content type should be `application/json`.

The following answer has an example of the differing formats that are passed by the various content types, which may be  contributing to your issues: [differences in application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523/differences-in-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-urlencoded/9880122#9880122)

Comment: Thank you @aslantorret for the link. Am I wrong in assuming that I should specify x-www-form-urlencoded as the content type had to be set to this in the header in `postman`to get a post request to work?