# Spring MVC / Simple Post request does not work

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-mvc, post

In my spring MVC app, I'm trying to make a simple Post request but it doesn't work because of the body of my request. I got nested objects in my params and Spring throws this exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'contrats[0][nomFichier]' of bean class [fr.mnh.signweb.dto.InitSignatureRQDTO]: Property referenced in indexed property path 'contrats[0][nomFichier]' is neither an array nor a List nor a Map; returned value was [fr.mnh.signweb.dto.ContratDTO@1c74fdf]
```

Here is the json sent to the request : (I didn't show the values)
[image]

And here is my object DTO :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class InitSignatureRQDTO {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String referenceFournisseur;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String produit;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String civilite;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String nom;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String prenom;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String email;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String telephone;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String rue;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String complementRue;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String codePostal;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String ville;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String pays;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<ContratDTO> contrats;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String messageSms;

}
```

And :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContratDTO {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String nomFichier;
    /*@Getter
    @Setter
    private byte[] fichier;*/

}
```

Here is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/initSign", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity launchSign(InitSignatureRQDTO initSignatureRQDTO) {

        System.out.println(initSignatureRQDTO);


    }
```

I tried to use @RequestBody like :

```
public ResponseEntity launchSign(@RequestBody InitSignatureRQDTO initSignatureRQDTO)
```

But it doesn't work. I have the x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 not supported exception.

EDIT :
When using :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/initSign", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity launchSign(InitSignatureRQDTO initSignatureRQDTO) {
```

I got these logs :

```
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet' processing POST request for [/initSign]
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /initSign
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [null]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

Comment: Sorry about offtopic but looks like you use Lombok. In this case you can apply \@Getter, \@Setter annotations for a class. There is no need to apply them for all class members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending JSON content in POST request body, so you need to use content type as `application/json` in your request.

`x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8` is to be used when you are submitting a form.

Comment: I've edited my question to show you what's going on when using consumes = Json

Comment: @whySoSerious You need to send your `Request` with header `content-type: application/json`

Comment: I used this header, but no mapping was done. Indeed it worked but I have null values in my java object.

Comment: You are one step closer. Can you post raw JSON which is sent ? I think your JSON looks something like `{"test":{"civilite":""}}` from the console log. It should be `{"civilite":""}`. i.e. without wrapping `test` object

Comment: I have the following message : DEBUG: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'fr.mnh.signweb.dto.InitSignatureRQDTO'
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'referenceFournisseur': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'referenceFournisseur': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Comment: The json was successfully built, there is not "test" ^^

Comment: Without actual JSON it's impossible to tell for sure. Can you include actual JSON content ?

Comment: I found what the solution, I had to use JSON.stringify in order to make it work. Thanks man ;)

Answer (score 0):

"*I have the x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 not supported exception.*" - I think here's the clue.

When you want to send the data such as your `InitSignatureRQDTO`, you would want to use `application/json`. 
This tells the server **that you are posting JSON data** as in:

```
{ Name : 'myname', email: 'myemail@email'}
```

Whereas `www-form-urlencoded` is used mostly when sending a small number of params. It will notify the server that **you will be encoding the parameters in the URL.**

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523/differences-in-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-urlencoded).

However, if you still want to use `www-form-urlencoded` , you might want to notify your control to accept that by something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/initSign", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
```

Comment: It worked with the header but I have null values in my java object, no mapping was done