# Dynamic javascript form with thymeleaf and Spring-boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a thymeleaf page which successfully uses javascript to generate a form. However I do not know how to make this dynamic form work with spring. Below is my HTML, the form part is down the bottom

HTML

```js
    var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
    
    h1.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

    timer();
}
function timer() {
 clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}



/* Start button */
start.onclick = timer;

/* Stop button */
stop.onclick = function() {
    clearTimeout(t);
}

/* Clear button */
clear.onclick = function() {
    h1.textContent = "00:00:00";
    seconds = 0; minutes = 0; hours = 0;
}

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
    
var count =0;   


function addFields(type){
 
 count = count + 1;
 
   
    var container = document.getElementById("container");

     container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Type"));
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = type;
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  Timestamp "));
        
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.value = document.getElementById("time").textContent;
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("  Details(optional)"));
        
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        container.appendChild(input);
        container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Match</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>

    
</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Match of ' + ${part1} + ' and ' + ${part2}"/>
<p id="demo"></p>

<table>

 <tr>
  <th>
   <p th:text="${part1}"/>
  </th>
  <th>
   <h1 id="time"><time >00:00:00</time></h1>
   <button id="start">start</button>
   <button id="stop">stop</button>
   <button id="clear">clear</button>
  </th>   
  <th>
   <p th:text="${part2}"/>
  </th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Ippon')" >Ippon!</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Ippon')">Ippon!</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Wazari')" >Wazari</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Wazari')">Wazari</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Shido')" >Shido</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields('Shido')">Shido</button>
  </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields(' ')" >Event</button>
  </td>
  <td>
   
  </td>
  <td>
   <button onclick="addFields(' ')" >Event</button>
  </td>
 </tr>

</table>  
<br/>

<a href="#" id="filldetails" onclick="addFields()" class="btn btn-default">Add event</a>
 
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/competition/save}" th:object="${match}" method="post">
  
    <div id="container"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>


</body>


</html>
```

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/competition/save")
public String matchPost(@Valid @RequestBody Match match) {

    return "match2";
}
```

When I hit submit I get "There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415). Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"

Comment: Remove `@RequestBody`?

Comment: You need to set correct content type for request body. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48991402/1497944

Comment: Thank you I read it, but it is not clear to me how I would do the syntax properly. Can you show me with my controller?