# SendMessage to SQS with HTTPS JSON body

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, https, amazon-sqs

I would like to send a HTTPS JSON POST request to AWS SQS, rather than url-encoded. I would like for the whole request, including the Action, the Attributes, the MessageBody, etc. to be within one JSON object.

I am currently trying to do so in Postman. When I do so with a url-encoded body that looks like:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody=Somemessage
&Expires=2020-10-15T12%3A00%3A00Z
&Version=2012-11-05
```

I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SendMessageResponse xmlns="http://queue.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-11-05/">
    <SendMessageResult>
        <MessageId>someid</MessageId>
        <MD5OfMessageBody>somemd5</MD5OfMessageBody>
    </SendMessageResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
        <RequestId>somerequestid</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</SendMessageResponse>
```

When I do so with a JSON body that looks like:

```
{
"Action":"SendMessage",
"MessageBody":"Somejsonmessage",
"Expires":"2020-10-15T12:00:00",
"Version":"2012-11-05"
}
```

I get:

```
<AccessDeniedException>
  <Message>Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized</Message>
</AccessDeniedException>
```

If I change this to:

```
Action=SendMessage&MessageBody={
"Action":"SendMessage",
"MessageBody":"Somejsonmessage",
"Expires":"2020-10-15T12:00:00",
"Version":"2012-11-05"
}
```

It works again, but I want to send the whole message as one JSON object.

I have been unable to find out whether or not using a JSON request body is actually legal. Their examples use url-encoded. Is sending a JSON request body legal for AWS SQS? Can you provide me an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sending JSON in encoded URL is not illegal. Its determined by Content-Type Header.
Refer [URL-Encoded vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523/differences-in-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-urlencoded)

Comment: I'm aware but this is specifically in regards to sending a JSON request to AWS SQS. I will go neaten up my post because it was not super clear about that. Sorry.