# Strava webhook event data not receive

Tags: php, webhooks, strava, strava-api-v3

I am working on project PHP need strava webhook to update strava user data any time their activity change.
I am official document for webhook here https://developers.strava.com/docs/webhooks/
I follow this code https://gist.github.com/erikdmitchell/2e165c57e618de14e1b208fceba2ee65 and make webhook call well to webhook.php

And this is my PHP code on webhook.php to receive the call from strava

```
$html = "";
$html = $html . '<hr/>' . json_encode($_GET) . '<hr/>' . json_encode($_POST) . '<hr/>' . json_encode($_REQUEST);
```

And my output for all of receive call from Strava

```
<hr/>[]<hr/>[]<hr/>[]
```

My problem is I tried many ways but can't get Event Data from strava webhook send to me. From my webhook.php file when Strava call to it, I don't see any more information from $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST

At least I need which user id has just add/delete/update their activity on strava

Welcome any of your solution...

Comment: Please provide a link to Strava's documentation for the webhook you want to receive. And then please provide _your_ code for receiving that webhook request _within your question_ (not someone else's code on another website) so we can see if you've done anything wrong. This is as per the official guidance: [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I has just updated my topic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right at the bottom of [the Strava documentation](https://developers.strava.com/docs/webhooks/) they show how to send a test event to your own webhook with curl.  They show POSTing a JSON body with `Content-Type: application/json`.  That means it is not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so there is no `$_POST`, and your webhook will need to work with the raw request body.

To do that, try something like this:

```
$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$json = json_decode($payload, true);

// See what it looks like
print_r($json);
```

References:

- [What are the differences between application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870523/what-are-the-differences-between-application-json-and-application-x-www-form-url)
- [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: Work really well for me. Thank you very much